# How to pretty print BeautifulSoup's string output

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have the following scraping code:

```
import requests, bs4

def make_soup():
    url = 'https://www.airbnb.pl/s/Girona--Hiszpania/homes?place_id=ChIJRRrTHsPNuhIRQMqjIeD6AAM&query=Girona%2C%20Hiszpania&refinement_paths%5B%5D=%2Fhomes&allow_override%5B%5D=&s_tag=b5bnciXv'
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
    return soup

def get_listings():
    soup = make_soup()
    listings = soup.select('._f21qs6')
    number_of_listings = len(listings)
    print("Current number of listings: " + str(number_of_listings))
    while number_of_listings != 18:
        print("Too few listings: " + str(number_of_listings))
        soup = make_soup()
        listings = soup.select('._f21qs6')
        number_of_listings = len(listings)
    print("All fine! The number of listings is: " + str(number_of_listings))
    return listings

new_listings = get_listings()
print(new_listings)
```

I think def `get_listings()` returns `listings` as string, so I cannot use BeautifulSoup's `prettify()` on it and `new_listings` gets printed as one block of text.

Is there any way to print `new_listings` in HTML-esque format or at least have each tag printed at separate line?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
type(new_listings)
# list
```

Shows that `new_listings` is a list. Try:

```
print(new_listings[0].prettify())
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
from pprint import pprint 
pprint(new_listings)
```

`pprint` beautifies much outputs cleanly.